# Hpricot and Rails Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rendering, hpricot

I finally managed to get Hpricot and Rails working together as below:

parser_controller:

def deck
    require 'hpricot'
    require 'open-uri'
    @doc = open("http://www.keo.co.za/") { |f| Hpricot(f) }
    end
end

deck view:

<%=(@doc/"#list-of-posts h2 ").inner_html%>

which gives me:

KeoTV: D-Day for desperate Boks

Which is awesome, but now I want to render it in a list instead of it just showing me html in one single line? How can I make it show it to me in another output visibly instead of just HTML?

Thanks